# Where to place custom Results, Filters and Attributes in ASP.NET MVC Solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, visual-studio-2012

This question is one of general class/file placement in a solution. In MVC3/4, if I am defining my own ActionResults, Filters and Attributes, where is the best place to store them?

I prefer to have my Solutions well organised and currently I have them in my \Models folder. Is this the best place to keep them from an architectural point of view?

Does anyone use specific folders for each of these types of classes, eg \Filters, \Results etc..

Thanks.

Comment: In my application I have added another class project for global action filters and attributes classes and calling them wherever I need in my project as generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my solutions I tend to folder off all types of 'similar' functionality e.g.

**Main Project:**

- Filters (this is generated by the new MVC4 folder structure anyway)
- Infrastructure (this will contain helpers and extensions etc.
- ActionResults
- Models (for the view models

**Second Project:**

- DTOs etc